# Integrate Gulp with TFS2013

Tags: javascript, .net, gulp, continuous-integration

I am trying yo integrate gulpjs with TFS 2013 (using VS2015 for my development). I couldnt find any proper documentation for this.

Can anyone point me to right solution?

Answer (score 0):

To use the Gulp in TFS 2013 xaml build, you could follow these steps below:

1. On the build agent server, install global gulp. Install this command using the TFS build service account. `npm install --global gulp-cli`
2. Create a batch file and use it to install local gulp and run gulp.

`@echo off`

`cd %TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY%\TestWebApp\WebApplication1`

```
npm install gulp --save-dev

gulp
```

Note: you could use `%TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY%` the [environment variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh850448%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to locate to your project folder.

3. Check in the batch file to TFS and run it before or after build.
   [image]